# long double (80 bits) twice as fast as double with -funsafe-math-optimizations

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, compiler-optimization

I'm getting consistently that using `long double` datatype is about twice as fast as using `double` for my calculations when using `-funsafe-math-optimizations`. I would like to have an insight on this, because the 80 bit format is deprecated since long,  or I might be doing something really dumb with the `double` datatype. The compiler is g++ 4.8.2, target is x86_64 (so gcc would prefer SSE2 if I don't use `long double`).

My code is more or less like this (pseudocode):

```
//x is an array of floating point numbers
for i -> x.size
        accumulator = 0
        for k -> kmax
            accumulator += A[k]*(B[k]*cos(C*k*x[i]) - D[k]*sin(C*k*x[i]));
        x[i] += F*accumulator;
        if(x[i] >= 1/2) x[i] -= integer(x[i]+1/2);
        else if(x[i] < -1/2) x[i] -= integer(x[i]-1/2);
```

`A`, `B`, .. are some precomputed arrays/constants.

The speedup seems unrelated to cacheline problems, because I get the same relative speedup if I parallelize the outer for loop with OpenMP.

EDIT:
I corrected the pseudocode: notice the `cos` and `sin` have the same argument, that is in the end the reason for the speedup (see gsg's answer and the comments).

Comment: Is there any change in the branch history of the `if` and `for` statements?

Comment: what is the assembler output for the two versions?

Comment: When using `long double`, are you using `cosl()` or `cos()`?

Comment: What is your source for “the 80 bit format is deprecated since long”?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I don't use any profile based optimization and the average number of times that the if/elseif is taken doesn't change.

Comment: @Jeff the compiler output does not give me any particular insight. But I am not good at reading assembly.

Comment: @chux c++'s `cos`, which is overloaded for `long double`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq 80 bit double means the x87 FPU unit is used, but the SSE2 unit is preferred in modern code, in fact you are guaranteed to have SSE2 instructions for x86_64 targets.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone You are guaranteed to have SSE2 instructions for x86_64 targets because these instructions are guaranteed to be available for these targets and they do exactly what could be expected for `float` or `double` (binary32 and binary64 operations). This does not mean that the 80-bit format is “deprecated”, nor does you saying that it is constitute a source.

Comment: @PascalCuoq correct, it's not the 80 bit format but the x87 unit as a whole. I didn't look for a source because you seem knowledgeable and for sure you know what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the difference is due to `cos`.

The `long double` math must be compiled into x87 instructions, making it easy and efficient to use the x87 operation `fcos`. However there are no transcendental operations for the `xmm` registers, so a call to cos must either generate code to move a `double` onto the x87 stack and invoke `fcos`, or make a function call to do the equivalent work. These are, presumably, more expensive for this compiler and machine.

You could try to verify this by looking at the assembly - look for `call cos` or x87 instructions - and it might also be worth compiling with `-mfpmath=387` to see if the performance characteristics change.

Comment: Going to check. Do you have an explanation for which this only happens with `-funsafe-math-optimizations`? Since when the x87 fcos is "unsafe"?

Comment: @LorenzoPistone The x87 trigonometric instructions have sub-par argument reduction on some models of processors. See http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/289702

Comment: Just going by observation: gcc has historically emitted a call to `cos` unless `-ffast-math` is specified, in which case it uses the `fcos` instruction. This decision may due to the fact that `cos(3)` is supposed to set `errno` for a `NaN` argument, but I am not certain.

Comment: I made a typo in the question: I don't have two `cos`, but a `cos` and a `sin` with the same argument. I see here in the assembly this instruction, `fsincos`, I'm pretty sure that's the reason of the dramatic speedup. Without `-funsafe-math-optimizations`, I get a call to `sincosl`.

Comment: @gsg I accepted your answer. Would be nice if you mention also this `fsincos` thing. Other operations like the `sqrt` seem not to be affected by `-funsafe-math-optimizations` being present or not.

Comment: Yes, if you take both `cos` and `sin` of the same value then an aggressive compiler will fold them into one operation (much like div and mod, they can be computed more efficiently together than separately). As for `sqrt`, the difficulty should not arise because there are SSE instructions designed to do the right thing for `double`s.